# React: Error 404 when loading local image

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I tried rendering a list of flyers with an image along with other properties. However, each time I tried loading images with the correct path, I seem to get an 404 error.

The error says `GET http://localhost:3000/assets/flyer1.png 404 (Not Found)` .

I am very confused, it seems to require me to start the backend to retrieve the image too, but it doesn't make sense in this context.

My code:

```
const myClass = () => {
    const events = [
        {
            "src": "../../assets/flyer1.png",
            "eventName": "Bruin Sunday",
            "eventTime": "October 11, 2020 3-4pm",
            "location": "TBD"
        },
        {
            "src": "../../assets/flyer2.png",
            "eventName": "Vision 2020",
            "eventTime": "October 17 12pm - 18 4pm, 2020",
            "location": "TBD"
        }
    ]

    /* Renders the list of flyers from json file */
    const flyerList = events.map((event) => {
        return(
            <Flyer src={event.src} alt={event.eventName} time={event.eventTime} location={event.location} />
        )
    })

    return (
        {flyerList}
    );
}
```

And Flyer is defined as such:

```
const Flyer = (props) => {

    return(
        <div className="flyer-container" 
        onMouseEnter={()=>{setHovering(true);}} 
        onMouseLeave={()=>{setHovering(false);}}>
            <img className="flyer-img" src={props.src} alt={props.alt}></img>
            <div className="flyer-info">
                <p>Event name: {props.eventName}</p>
                <p>Event time: {props.eventTime}</p>
                <p>Location: {props.location}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Any insight helps! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to find any error in your code I think just try to change the relative path to absolute path for the "src" variable it might start working because certain times there seems to be conflicts in the path like the browser is unable to find the exact location of the file. Hope so it might start working.